# java coding style: one annotation with parameters, or several annotations with just one?

Tags: java, annotations, styles

I have got an annotation with about 10 parameters, all optional.
But in case you use them, it may look like this:

`@myAnnotation(oneFlag anotherFlag parameter="value")`.

Splitting the one annotation into several, the example would look like this:

`@oneFlag @anotherFlag @parameter("value")`;

Which "good java style" criterial exist for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect it depends how cohesive the annotations are. For example:

Bad (difficult to tell which annotations relate to each other):

```
@Transaction(Isolation.DEFAULT)
@TransactionRollbackFor(Bar.class)
@ReadOnly // Not actually related to transactions
public class Foo { }
```

Good:

```
@Transactional(isolation=Isolation.DEFAULT,rollbackFor=Bar.class)
@ReadOnly
public class Foo { }
```